# How can I create 2 subsites (at the same level) without one being aware of the other?

Tags: permissions, access

I have a site collection called Vendors. I need to create a sub-site for each of my vendors, so I do so by creating a new sub-site with unique permissions.

The problem is that when users of the 'vendor1' sub-site clicks on

Site Settings -> People and Groups, --> More

He is able to see

```
- vendor1 members
- vendor1 visitors
- vendor1 owners
- vendor2 members
- vendor2 visitors
- vendor2 owners
```

How can I make it so that users of vendor1 can only see groups of the vendor1 sub-site and users of vendor2 can only see groups of the vendor2 subsite?

Here is my site structure

```
                           vendors (Site collection)
                        /          \
                       /            \
                      /              \
                   vendor1          vendor2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Restrict permissions for the users - do not allow to go to settings/permission page.

2) Separate site collections

Comment: How would you not allow the users to go the Settings/Permissions?

Comment: When you are assigning permissions add them just Read/Contribute. You can check each permission capabilities under Site permissions -> Permission levels - and click on selected permission. You will see allowed operation for each permission level. If this is not sufficient for you, you can also define new perm. levels.